# How to get the output of a wpf datepicker selected date in a specific text format c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I have a SQLite database table with multiple columns.

The model representing that looks something like this

```
public class Bills : ViewModelBase
{
    
    private int _id;
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ref _id, value);
        }
    }

    private string _billDt;
    public string BillDt
    {
        get
        {
            return _billDt;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ref _billDt, value);
        }
    }

    private string _amt;
    public string Amt
    {
        get
        {
            return _amt;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ref _amt, value);
        }
    }

    private string _dueDt;
    public string DueDt
    {
        get
        {
            return _dueDt;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ref _dueDt, value);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Now I've created a CRUD form for saving/editing data with some text boxes for some fields and Datepicker's for date fields like `BillDt`, `DueDt` etc.

The datepicker's XAML looks something like this

```
                <DatePicker
                    FontSize="14"
                    SelectedDate="{Binding BillDt, BindingGroupName=Group1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="3"/>
```

I've also added some styling in app.xaml resources like

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                             Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='dd-MM-yyyy',
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

What I'm trying to do is when I save the data to my database the data of `BillDt`, `DueDt` should be saved in the format yyyy-MM-dd and when it is displayed in the Datepicker's it would show them in the format dd-MM-yyyy.

Currently the already stored data in the database table have the `BillDt`, `DueDt` values in the format yyyy-MM-dd and when I search them in my CRUD form they are shown in the desired format i.e. dd-MM-yyyy but when I make some changes using the Datepicker's and save it, the values are stored in the database tables in the format dd-MM-yyyy 00:00:00 instead of the desired format of yyyy-MM-dd.

How do I fix this ? Do I need to use some variation of IValueConverter or something like that ? How do I use it in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can parse it in the getter, so when stored in db it will be in "yyyy-MM-dd" format

```
public string DueDt
{
    get
    {
        var b = DateTime.TryParse(_dueDt, out DateTime dt);
        return b ? dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : _dueDt;
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ref _dueDt, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried your approach, so far works great.